# Retrieving MySQL time in java

Tags: java, mysql, time, resultset

I am running the following query to get time difference of two times

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TIMEDIFF('14:03:55.256', '14:02:51.780') AS td");
```

MySQL gives time difference in this format

```
00:01:03.476
```

But both
    [`resultSet.getTime("td");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTime%28java.lang.String%29) and [`resultSet.getObject("td");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28java.lang.String%29)

returns `00:01:03`

According to the documentation [`getTime(String string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTime%28java.lang.String%29) retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) object in the Java programming language.

 `java.sql.Time` corresponds to SQL TIME and contains information about *hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds*.Then why am I getting `00:01:03` instead of `00:01:03:476`?

What I basically want is to store `00:01:03.476` into a String. Is there any workaround or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: have you tried `resultSet.getString("td")`?

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, but it throws `java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time '00:01:03.476' in column 1`

Answer (score 4):

If you are verifying the result by printing it out note that [`java.sql.Time.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#toString%28%29) only returns a string in the format `hh:mm:ss`

You should really use `rs.getTimestamp` which will return a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: I am verifying the result by `System.out.println(resultSet.getTime("td"))` and `resultSet.getTimestamp()` throws `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '00:01:03.476' from column 1 to TIMESTAMP.`

Comment: Try this then `new Timestamp(resultSet.getTime("td").getTime())`. Note that by wrapping the resulting time object in a println `toString()` is being called.

Comment: It is returning `1970-01-01 00:01:03.0`. The problem is that `resultSet.getTime("td")` is itself returning `00:01:03` so, `getTime()` just adds 0 ms to it.

Comment: If this is the case then it is the Driver that you are using implementation of the `ResultSet.getTime()` which is cutting off the milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this:

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss.SSS").format(t.getTime());
```

where `t` is your variable of type `java.sql.Time`.

Hope this will solve you problem.

Comment: but it doesn't work if the column value is NULL, throws null pointer exception

Comment: @ParagJadhav if your column accepts nulls you have to treat for nulls at the code. If nulls are undesireable and you can modify the database, mark the column as not null.